# dynamic urls and session variables using sql in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

im trying to get my links dynamic that way the code automatically makes the navigate url. This is probably a relatively simple. Right now i'm using a gridview with this code:

```
Bind("EventID", "{0}")
```

right now it goes to `/folder/1` or whatever the `EventID` is in the sql database

i'm trying to make it so it goes to `page.aspx/EventName-EventID` that way it I don't have to create a new folder each time.

Answer (score 0):

Is EventName in the database?  Assuming it is, the url would be something like:

```
='<%#"page.aspx/" + Bind("EventName") + "-" + Bind("EventID") %>'
```